# Vagrant chef_solo provisioner raising NoMethodError - undefined method 'default_attributes' for #<Hash: ....>

Tags: json, vagrant, chef-infra, provisioning, chef-solo

I'm trying to provision a VM using Vagrant in order to test a cookbook (chef-mycookbooks-test) I created. It depends on data_bags in chef-repo. I can't find any answers as to why this isn't working.

The VM starts up fine but it throws an exception when it runs chef-solo:

```
INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[mycookbooks-test::default]"] from CLI options
DEBUG: Applying attributes from json file
Error expanding the run_list:
NoMethodError: undefined method `default_attributes' for #<Hash:0x0000000384e3a7>
```

I don't know if it matters, but the environment I'm using (local.json) has default_attributes defined. When I log on to the VM and look at solo.rb I see some of the data from my provisioning (eg. environment "local") but not all of it (eg. no role set, default cookbook_path, role_path is []). I get the same error when I try to run chef-solo from the VM manually.

Directory structure on host machine:

```
.
├── chef-repo
│   ├── data_bags
│   │   ├── groups
│   │   │   └── test.json
│   │   └── users
│   │       └── test.json
│   ├── environments
│   │   └── local.json
│   └── roles
│       └── test_server.json   
└── chef-mycookbooks-test
    ├── Berksfile
    ├── Berksfile.lock
    ├── Vagrantfile
    ├── files
    │   └── default
    │       └── sudoers.test
    ├── metadata.rb
    └── recipes
        └── default.rb
```

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
    config.vm.box = "hansode/centos-6.3-x86_64"
    config.berkshelf.enabled = true

    config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
        chef.cookbooks_path = ".."
        chef.data_bags_path = "../chef-repo/data_bags"
        chef.environments_path = "../chef-repo/environments"
        chef.environment = "local"
        chef.roles_path = "../chef-repo/roles"
        chef.add_role("test_server")
        chef.run_list = [
            "recipe[mycookbooks-test::default]"
        ]
    end
end
```

Interestingly, if I remove the line defining chef.environment, the run_list expands just fine to [mycookbooks-test::default], but chef-solo fails later when it tries to run some of the dependencies, for which the environment data is needed.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I am completely out of ideas.

Note: I cleaned up some of the unnecessary things in the directory tree (eg. README.md) and Vagrantfile (eg. debug level) for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like `cookbooks_path` are relative to the host machine, not the guest. Are you sure you really have your cookbooks at `/`? Chances are you are loading a bunch of invalid data and Chef is choking on it. You can also up your logging level via `chef.log_level = :debug`.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I cleaned up some stuff in the file for easier reading. I do have my log level set to debug and I was testing the cookbooks path but had originally had it set to "..". I've fixed both in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: You still have `chef.roles_path = "/chef-repo/roles"`. Is your stuff literally at `/chef-repo`?

Comment: Thanks, I guess I thought these things were relative to the location on the VM (hence syncing my chef-repo). I guess Vagrant takes care of these things. I changed data_bags_path and roles_path to be relative to the host machine but I still get the same error.

Comment: Does your role JSON contain the required `json_class` and `chef_type` keys?

Comment: Yes:

"json_class": "Chef::Role",
"chef_type": "role",

Comment: How about the environment?

Comment: It was not in the environment. Added ..."json_class": "Chef::Environment",
 "chef_type": "environment",... to the environment JSON and that fixed it. Thank you so much!